# Local storage lost after restart chrome and web app

Tags: web-applications, local-storage, google-chrome-app

Into a chrome web app, I show a website.
This website saves some datas to localstorage.

Example:
`localStorage.setItem("testkey", "testvalue");`

Whe I start the web app, it saves the datas to localstorage. I can close the app, and start it again. The testkey is available.

When I close the app, and chrome browser, and restart everything, all saved datas into localstorage are lost.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: With a <webview>?